# Selenium, webDrive, chrome, java: Third Part Cookies

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, cookies

sorry for my bad english!
there is a metod with Webdriver, in java, for count the third part cookies!?!?
I should count how many request there are without Adblock Plus(or similar), and how many request there are with Adblock active!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in WebDriver for getting the cookies:

```
allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

According to the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html), this returns a Set. You could then call `allCookies.size()` to find out how many there are.